# Concise way of deserializing json to an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a config service which wraps the baked-in assembly settings, but I'd also like to override these on the command line.
Currently this code is working fine:

```
    public interface ISettings
    {
        string Url { get; }
    }

    public class OperationalSettings : ISettings
    {
        public string Url { get { return ServiceSettings.Default.Url; } }
    }

    public class CommandLineModel
    {
        public string Url;
    }

    public class CommandLineSettings : ISettings
    {
        private readonly CommandLineModel _model;

        public CommandLineSettings(string serialisedSettings)
        {
            _model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CommandLineModel>(serialisedSettings);
        }

        public string Url { get { return _model.Url; } }
    }

    public class ConfigService
    {
        private readonly ISettings _settings;
        public ConfigService(ISettings settings)
        {
            _settings = settings;
        }
        public ISettings settings { get { return _settings; } }
    }
```

Then the test driver code:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ISettings opSettings = new OperationalSettings();

            var commandLineTest = "{Url:'http://overridenurl.com'}";

            ISettings commandSettings = new CommandLineSettings(commandLineTest);

            var configService = new ConfigService(opSettings);
            var configServiceUsingCmdOpts = new ConfigService(commandSettings);
        }
    }
```

So with this I can override settings using the command line string. However, what I don't like is that if I have a new settings, I now need to add this in 4 places:

- The interface
- The concrete implementation of the settings wrapper (OperationalSettings)
- The command line model for deserialisation
- The command line settings implementation that wraps the deserialised model.

This seems to suffer from scalability once I add more properties. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this without so many code changes?

Comment: you could take a look at dynamic object  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel I've swapped out CommandLineModel with dynamic and this seems to work well. Is this the only solution?

Comment: Take a look at my answer there is also a built-in object that might be useful in your case

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at `DynamicObject`

```
  public class CommandLineModelDictionary : DynamicObject
    {
        // The inner dictionary.
        Dictionary<string, object> dictionary
            = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        // This property returns the number of elements
        // in the inner dictionary.
        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return dictionary.Count;
            }
        }

        // If you try to get a value of a property 
        // not defined in the class, this method is called.
        public override bool TryGetMember(
            GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            // Converting the property name to lowercase
            // so that property names become case-insensitive.
            string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

            // If the property name is found in a dictionary,
            // set the result parameter to the property value and return true.
            // Otherwise, return false.
            return dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result);
        }

        // If you try to set a value of a property that is
        // not defined in the class, this method is called.
        public override bool TrySetMember(
            SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            // Converting the property name to lowercase
            // so that property names become case-insensitive.
            dictionary[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;

            // You can always add a value to a dictionary,
            // so this method always returns true.
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Otherwise If you have a simple scenario in which you need an object that can only add and remove members at run time but that does not need to define specific operations and does not have static members, use the `ExpandoObject` class

here how to use

```
class Program
    {
        public static dynamic Dyn { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          dynamic model= new  CommandLineModelDictionary();
            model.Prop1 = "Foo";
            model.Prop2 = "toto";  



             Console.WriteLine(model.Prop1);
            Console.WriteLine(model.Prop2);
            //otherwise you can use 
            dynamic dynModel = new ExpandoObject();
            dynModelop1 = "Test1";
            dynModel2 = "Test2";  
            Console.WriteLine(dynModel.Prop1);
            Console.WriteLine(dynModel.Prop2);


        }
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that really I need to be able to get the current assembly settings, and then override them with the dynamic properties set on the command line via json.  A little bit like Jquery extend. I tried AutoMapper but struggled to get this to work.